# Prevent closing cell editor in popup mode on outside click

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have custom text editor in table cell, after I select text in it I want to use top page panel to make it bold (outside of the table), but when I click on the button (on the top page panel) this  action closes cell editor popup.

Is it posible to keep the cell editor open in popup mode after I click on buttons outside of the table?

Comment: have got any workaround for this

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of ag-grid (v24), clicking outside the grid does not close a popup editor, unless you set `stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus` to true in the options.

See their example: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#example-dynamic-parameters